# JqGrid: Only able to retrieve selected id of current page

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a Jqgrid with `multiselect =true` option along with the paging . My page size is 10 and during editing if there are more record then the page size it goes onto 2 page . This is working fine .

My query is if i am on current page and directly save the data without going to the nextpage then my array only 10 record and that data is saved other record are deleted.

Kindly help me to rectified the issue

Here is my code

```
    $("#WorkerMigrationSearchGrid").jqGrid({
    datatype: '',
    height: 340,
    width: 910,
    colNames: ['WorkerID', 'Worker Name', 'IC / FIN', 'WP No', 'BusinessUnitID', 'PrimarySubContractorID', 'Status', 'PrimaryTradeID'],
    colModel: [
    { name: 'WorkerID', index: 'WorkerAttendanceID', width: 1, hidden: true },
    { name: 'Worker', index: 'Worker', width: 200, sortable: false },
    { name: 'IdentificationNumber', index: 'IdentificationNumber', width: 50, sortable: false },
    { name: 'WPNumber', index: 'WPNumber', width: 50, sortable: false },
    { name: 'BusinessUnitID', index: 'ScanTime', width: 90, sortable: false, hidden: true },
    { name: 'PrimarySubContractorID', index: 'ScanType', width: 30, sortable: false, hidden: true },
    { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', width: 1, hidden: true },
    { name: 'PrimaryTradeID', index: 'PrimaryTradeID', width: 1, hidden: true }
],
    multiselect: true,
    caption: "Select Worker",
    pager: jQuery('#pager'),
    viewrecords: true,
    scrollrows: true,
    shrinkToFit: true,
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 15, 20],        // disable page size dropdown
    pgbuttons: true,
    pgtext: "Page {0} of {1}",
    altRows: true,
    onSelectAll: function (rowid, isSelected) {
        idsOfSelectedRows = [];

        if (isSelected) {

            var i, count, id
            for (i = 0, count = rowid.length; i < count; i++) {
                id = rowid[i];
                updateIdsOfSelectedRows(id, isSelected);

            }

        }
        //idsOfSelectedRows.push(id);
    },
    onSelectRow: function (id, isSelected) {
        updateIdsOfSelectedRows(id, isSelected);
    },
    gridComplete: function () {
        var i, selCount;
        for (i = 0, selCount = idsOfSelectedRows.length; i < selCount; i++) {

            row = $("#WorkerMigrationSearchGrid").getRowData(idsOfSelectedRows[i])

            if (row["WorkerID"] != undefined) {

                jQuery("#WorkerMigrationSearchGrid").jqGrid('setSelection', row["WorkerID"]);

            }

        }

    },
    onPaging: function (pgButton) {
        SearchWorker();
    }
});

var updateIdsOfSelectedRows = function (id, isSelected) {
    var p = $("#WorkerMigrationSearchGrid").p, item = $("#WorkerMigrationSearchGrid").getRowData(id);
    item.cb = isSelected;
    i = $.inArray(id, idsOfSelectedRows);
    if (!isSelected && i >= 0) {

        idsOfSelectedRows.splice(i, 1); // remove id from the list

    } else if (i < 0) {

        idsOfSelectedRows.push(id);

    }
}
```

Comment: Is any thing is required . Please help me on urgent basis.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for this...

Comment: it is not possible because it is using json data and there is a Save button which is passed to the web method for saving

Comment: Please help to find solution